# USARSim and ROS integration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I have my own map and robot placed in the Map through USARSim. Since I have installed USARSim in Windows7 and ROS runs on Linux. So; what should I do--1)install ROS and USARSim both in Linux or 2)On windows7 use virtualbox to install Linux and then on Linux install ROS?**

**Question 2**: Which version of ROS should be installed? Groovy or hydro?
**Question 3**: Gazebo or Usarsim which one is best to work with ROS?

***Has anyone correctly use this framework upto high level navigation? I am stuck at creation of 2D global map.***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76855/usarsim-and-ros-integration/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be worth considering to use [USARSimROS](http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/wiki/Robotic%20Arms/) (it might be developed by someone in development team of USARSim at Georgia Tech though I'm not sure). Looks like it's actively maintained, although from [this wiki page](http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/wiki/Robotic%20Arms/) I sensed that it may have been tested with ROS `electric` and `fuerte`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-05**:
Hello, IsaacSaito. as I find some bugs in USARSimROS, so I decided to write my own node to communicate with ROS. I want to use its gmapping and laser scan messege and teleop package. For High level navigation I Will only refer to 2D map....Can I do that?

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-07**:
I confirm that USARSimROS is pretty buggy. There are at least two:

1. messages from ROS are not correctly routed to USARSim (actually speed commands are considered sensors measurements!)
2. the tf tree misses some nodes (in particular, the /lms200)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-11-10**:
@kr1zz I'm not a maintainer. Opening tickets for what you observed might be appreciated by its users and developers http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/tickets/

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-10**:
Hi @IsaacSaito, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the ticketing system seems closed (or, at least, I did not manage to open a new one :P ). However I mailed the authors about these issues some times ago.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-11**:
Hinomiyagura Team Description Paper for
Robocup 2013 Virtual Robot League uses USARSim/ROS..and MRL Team Description Paper for Virtual Robots Competition 2013 also uses USARSimROS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For 1 it really depends on what you want to do.  My guess is that 1) is going to be easiest with both running on the same machine.

For 2 groovy is more mature and has more capabilities.  However if hydro has the feature set you want released then it's going to be slightly newer and more up to date.

For 3 Gazebo is very closely integrated with ROS and I believe the majority of users use it with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can import UDK scenarios into USARSim, so you can have many huge worlds with a little effort (although there may be scaling issues from unreal units to metric).
I am trying to work with USARSimRos, as suggested by @IsaacSaito and, although the idea looks good, I found some bugs in it

---

Originally posted by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) with karma: 116 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-09-30**:
More details here: http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/discussion/general/thread/baca98c8/
Sorry but I cannot put urls into the answer :P

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-09-30**:
Thanks for the valuable information kr1zz. Now I am facing connection problem, I am pasting a portion here,

[ERROR] [1380608092.814006960]: connect
[ERROR] [1380608092.814131851]: can't open socket to localhost port 3000
[ERROR] [1380608092.814522262]: Error from usarsimInf, exiting

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-09-30**:
I wonder wether we are going off topic. However, that's a problem with the launch file you are using, since you try to connect to localhost, which I guess is a linux box, while USARSim should be running on a windows host

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-01**:
Hi, kr1zz that' why I post a new question related to this. My USARSim run on windows only and ROS on ubuntu 10.04 and I try to connect through LAN wire. And launch file looks fine..

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-01**:
Can you paste the .launch file, please?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-01**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/85786/usarsimlaunch-file-is-there-any-error/
Go to the link. If I paste whole file then some portion is not visible.

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2016-10-17**:
I am able to connect ROS-USARsim but while running teleop

```
 rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
```

every time i press the key , it says

```
 [ERROR] [1411920792.568087748]: usarsimInf::peerMsg: not handling type SW_SEN_ENCODER
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please type following commands on the terminal window of PC2.

```
$ echo “source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash” >> ~/.bashrc
$ . ~/.bashrc
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep ros-fuerte-brown-remotelab ros-fuerte-control ros-fuerte-common-msgs ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping ros-fuerte-hector-slam
$ rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
$ echo “source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash” >> ~/.bashrc
$ mkdir ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
$ source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
$ rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
$ source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
$ roscd
$ cd sandbox
$ git clone git://git.assembla.com/usarsim.git
(Under the proxy, try “git clone http://git.assembla.com/usarsim.git&#8221 )
$ rosmake usarsim_inf
```

---

Originally posted by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) with karma: 77 on 2014-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1